# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner isn't recognized as a type

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

My aplication uses Spring 4.3.1 and JUnit 4.12.

I have been trying test my methods with JUnit test cases.

I placed the **@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)** annotation in my test class, but eclipse complains "Class cannot be resolved to a type".

I read that this was enough for Eclipse to recognize SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, but isn't.

Is there Anything else remaining to do?

Comment: As any other class, you need to import it, or to use its fully qualified name.

Comment: Eclipse don't show me the import option when i opened the list of options to solve this issue. So I thought there was another problem

Comment: did you add the `spring-test` dependency.

Comment: I added this dependency now, but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1. Add spring-starter-test dependency through your configuration file & include relevant import statements in test files.
2. Delete local dependency repository & force new build to your application.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but HOW DO WE KNOW WHAT THE "relevant import statements" ARE?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the dependency **spring-test** the problem has been solved.

I didn't know there was need for this additional dependence, but someone told me here. Thank you.

I initially said that this measure was not enough because I had written the dependency version name wrongly and Maven was not finding the resource. But now it works!